# Link between Oracle APEX and Oracle Applications

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

Is there any link between Oracle Applications Users and Oracle APEX? Why we need this link between them is we want to provide set of Application Users to access some Reports in Oracle APEX what we have created.

Instead of creating users separately and assigning to the Workspace, Is there any way to use application users login to apex environment ?

Regards,
Bharat

Comment: Is oracle-apps actually e-Business Suite?

Comment: You need to look at the Oracle Single SignOn (SSO) setup for APEX. And the External user validation, which is separate. Depending on how you have your e-Business Suite applications configured.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use SSO for EBS versions 11i and above.

[Oracle Support Document 1306563.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1306563.1) gives a complete solution on how to integrate the two for R12.1. If you are using 11i, see [this whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/apex-ebs-wp-cabot-consulting-169064.pdf) by Rod West.

Your EBS users do not need to be created in APEX , merely authenticated and authorised.

Once you have set up your integration, your APEX environment is referenced in an FND Profile Option and your SSWA JSP menu functions point to a JSP file, which takes parameters for application, page etc.

You can customise the JSP to suit your integration needs.